# Add and Edit scheduled tasks via C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a windows service that resides on a windows 2008 server.  I also developed a separate C# winforms application that I'd like to use to configure a task for the service to schedule its run.

The winforms app is a form UI with basic scheduling inputs such as day of week, time of day, etc.  I'd lke the user to choose inputs and save this as a task that will schedule the running of my win service.

Is there a way to add/edit a windows scheduled task via C# winform without using 3rd party add-ons?

Comment: If it's a real [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6(v=VS.80).aspx) and it is registered on your service host, you can send commands like 'pause', 'stop', 'resume' and 'start' to control the service. Using the `System.ServiceProcess` namespace.

Comment: Does your service stop when it's done running?  Does it start automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could write the service to always be running, and have it reference a database table on when it should run.  The service would simply check when it is allowed to run.

Your WinForm application could simply update the database table.  Quite simple really.  Of course you could make it infinitely more complex, but, for what you are describing seems relatively simple.

Comment: I have a config file I can store the schedule data in.  But wouldn't the service need to constantly check the config to see if its time to run or not?

Comment: Sure it could be backed by a configuration file as well.  It all really depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way using purely managed code, but if you add a reference to the [TASK Scheduler COM Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614.aspx), you should be able to do it.  (References... Add Reference... Com Objects)

Comment: Or maybe, using [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(v=VS.85).aspx)